# Hosting ASP.NET Web site using IIS7 Windows 7

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, iis, iis-7, iis-8

I have made a small ASP.NET web site using VB 2010 and SQL 2008.
But I don't know how to host it on local PC.
The target PC is running windows 8.
All other PC's are connected it through LAN
The system is offline.
But before trying to host my web site on target PC (Windows 8) i want to make sure everything is ok with my site.
Hence I am first trying to host it on my PC (Windows 7).
I don't know anything about hosting on Windows 8 OS.
But I tried little bit on Windows 7 OS.
All I know is I am going to host my site on IIS7.
I already enabled IIS7 on my PC (Windows 7).
And I pasted all contents in my project folder to `C:\inetpub\wwwroot`
My default page is `C:\inetpub\wwwroot\index.aspx`
Now how do I add my website to IIS7 and attach database to it.
Do I need to install VB 2010 and SQL 2008 on target PC (Windows 8)?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Where is the database supposed to live in the end? If it is on the Target PC then yes it will need SQL 2008 but not if there is another server that is going to be the database server. You aren't clear about whether the site is supposed to all run on one server or if you have a multi-server set up where there is a web server and a separate database server.

Which version of the .Net Framework does the site use and is that registered with IIS?

Those would be my initial questions as you shouldn't have to install VB 2010 but you would need the Framework to be installed and configured to have this work.

---

EDIT: You will have to install and configure SQL Server 2008 on the machine. IIS can use .Net 2.0 or 4.0 and thus be aware of what configuration you want to run so that you don't wind up having issues.

Comment: thanks for response. There no separate database server. All things must be reside on target PC. I am not sure about .NET Framework on target PC. But I konow one thing that i it is disabled and i need to freshly enabled it.I am taking about IIS